# Pass hashmap to array adapter in Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I just want to pass a hashmap to array adapter in android. It is not going to be used for display. It is for some manipulation purpose. For display already a arraylist is passed.
Suggest how to just pass hashmap to adapter ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your adapter, please using values[] as hashMap.keys

Answer (score 0):

two possibilities

1. Add a parameter to the `Constructor`
2. create a setter

of course you have to write your own subclass of `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: I didnt get "subclass of array adapter", can you give some link or example plz ?